# Creating command based in array with horizontal and vertical lines

Tags: matrices

I want to make a command taking the input for an array and resulting into an array with lines separating entries. A particular case of the kind of array I want would be the following:

```
\[\left[\begin{array}{c|c|c|c}
1 & 2 & 3 & 4\\
\hline 4 & 5 & 6 & 6 \end{array}\right]\]
```

[image]

In general, I want to make something like the following

```
\newcommand{\sgna}[1]{\left[\begin{array}{c|c|c|c}#1 \end{array}\right]}
```

But I don't want to specify the number of 'c|' that I want to put, and I don't know how to make the array draw the horizontal lines after each row without modifying the input. I'd like the command to count the number of columns and rows and put the corresponding number of vertical and horizontal lines.
Is there any way to do that? It doesn't need to be a command. If needed it might be an environment.

This is a minimal example

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand{\sgna}[1]{\left[\begin{array}{c|c|c|c|c}#1 \end{array}\right]}
\begin{document}
%Particular case
\[\left[\begin{array}{c|c|c|c}
1 & 2 & 3 & 4\\
\hline 4 & 5 & 6 & 6 \end{array}\right]\]
%Resulting command if I put too many |c's
\[\sgna{1 & 2 & 3 & 4\\
4 & 5 & 6 & 6}\]
\end{document}
```

which draws

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One line with `nicematrix`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\newcommand{\sgna}[1]{\begin{bNiceMatrix}[margin,hvlines]#1\end{bNiceMatrix}}

\begin{document}

$\sgna{1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 4 & 5 & 6 & 6 }$

\end{document}
```

[image: Result of the above code]

Comment: That's a nice package. I was wondering if the "One line" meant only worked for two rows but tested it and it's exactly what I wanted. I think by that you meant that it only takes one line of code. Thanks.

Comment: Yes. I wanted to say : one line of code.